# How to run more than one test but not all the tests in GEB?

Tags: groovy, gradle, spock, geb

I am running gradle to run the tests from Windows command line. What I do to run a single test is:

```
gradlew.bat chromeTest -DchromeTest.single=test1Spec
```

or for all the tests:

```
gradlew.bat chromeTest
```

If I try to run only two test classes like this:

```
gradlew.bat chromeTest -DchromeTest=test1Spec,test2Spec--info
```

then gradle starts to run all the tests.

What I need: is to run only 2 or 3 Groovy classes. To be specific, neither one nor all. Any help would be really beneficial!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run more than one test but not all the tests in GEB using Gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433908/how-to-run-more-than-one-test-but-not-all-the-tests-in-geb-using-gradle)