# How to run more than one test but not all the tests in GEB using Gradle?

Tags: gradle, spock, geb

I am running gradle to run the tests from Windows command line. What I do to run a single test is:

```
gradlew.bat chromeTest -DchromeTest.single=test1Spec
```

or for all the tests:

```
gradlew.bat chromeTest
```

If I try to run only two test classes like this:

```
gradlew.bat chromeTest -DchromeTest=test1Spec,test2Spec--info
```

then gradle starts to run all the tests.

What I need: is to run only 2 or 3 Groovy classes. To be specific, neither one nor all. Any help would be really beneficial! Sorry, for reposting this question again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-DtestTaskName` supports wildcards such as `Test*Spec` or `foo.bar.*Spec`, but is limited to a single pattern. If you need support for multiple patterns, you'll have to implement your own command line parameter (which in the simplest case means reading a system property) and use that to configure `Test#include` or `Test#getFilter`. (See `Test` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) for details.)

Gradle 1.10 introduced `--tests` as a replacement for `-DtestTaskName`, but again, only one pattern is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Since Gradle [2.13](https://docs.gradle.org/2.13/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_test) it's possible to specify multiple patterns with `--tests` parameter, because starting in this documentation's version the following part (in bold) is added in the description:

> Command line option “--tests” is provided to conveniently set the test
> filter. Especially useful for the classic 'single test method
> execution' use case. When the command line option is used, the
> inclusion filters declared in the build script are ignored. **It is
> possible to supply multiple “--tests” options and tests matching any
> of those patterns will be included.**

Then the follow command works:

```
gradle test --tests some.pattern.class --tests different.pattern.class
```

Also as @PeterNiederwieser explains, you can configure `TestFilter` in your `build.gradle` including or excluding differents patterns for package, classes and methods. The follow example is from the [gradle api documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestFilter.html):

```
test {
       filter {
          //specific test class, this can match 'SomeTest' class and corresponding method under any package
          includeTestsMatching "SomeTest"
          includeTestsMatching "SomeTest.someTestMethod*"
          ...

          //specific test class and method
          includeTestsMatching "org.gradle.SomeTest.someSpecificFeature"
          includeTest "org.gradle.SomeTest", "someTestMethod"

          ...

          //exclude a specific test by its name
          excludeTestsMatching "*canDoSomethingSpecific"
          //excluding tests by name also works for test names which have spaces
          excludeTestsMatching "*can do something specific"
       }
   }
```